# Twig math with variables

Tags: math, twig

I want to do some math in twig. I've got 2 variables, price and quantity and i want to multiply them. But when I do it like this:

```
{{ {{ carts.price }} * {{ carts.quantity }} }}
```

It returns an error

```
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{".
```

How can i do this

Comment: `{{ carts.price * carts.quantity }}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you duplicate `{}`, try something like this : 
`{{ carts.price * carts.quantity }}`

some docs https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#math